# How does the body avoid making an immune response to self-antigens?

Tags: immunology, immune-system, autoimmune

The body contains antigen-detecting and presenting cells (APCs) including leukocytes and cytokines each having their characteristic HLA genes consisting of different recognition sites that detect the foreign molecules. Although the immune system can respond to a huge amount of different proteins or other antigens, self-antigens are not attacked by the immune system. Why not?

Comment: Check the terminology you're using, like "antigen", and see that you are using it properly. As-is, I think someone can guess at what you are writing here but the way it's actually written is nonsensical. For example, do *antigens* "attack"?

Comment: related, but not quite duplicate: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64897/autoimmunity-negative-selection-of-t-cells-apc. https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14067/autoimmunity-and-central-tolerance. Not sure if there's a good duplicate on self-tolerance that I missed though

Comment: @hali--the phenomenon you're asking about is "immune tolerance", or more specifically, "self immune tolerance". Those are helpful terms to google

Comment: Cytokines are not cells, they are proteins.

Comment: short answer, because your thymus tests every antigen binding protein against all your bodies antigens , helpful video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmpuerlbJu0